# Estimating $\sqrt{n}\approx a+\frac{n-a^2}{b^2-a^2}$, where $a^2$ and $b^2$ are the perfect squares nearest non-square $n$. Is it already known?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

A long time ago, I developed a technique for estimating irrational square roots.  I accepted it for the longest time as accurate as I noticed it produced consistently accurate results, though the calculation was always an underestimate.

Only recently have I developed the personal tools to prove this technique works for larger and larger irrational square roots.  That is, I was able to prove that my technique converges towards the square root function as we estimate irrational roots towards infinity.

Now, I am curious, is this technique already known?  If so, does it have a name?

My technique:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $\sqrt{n}$ is not an integer. Find the nearest integers to $n$ that are perfect squares.  Call them $a^2$ and $b^2$. Then my estimate will be:
> $$\sqrt{n} = a+ \frac{n-a^2}{b^2-a^2}$$

For example: Estimate $\sqrt{160452}$

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{160452} &\approx 400 + \frac{160452 - 400^2}{401^2 - 400^2} \\[4pt]
\sqrt{160452} &\approx 400.56460153139 \\[4pt]
\frac{160452 - 400^2}{401^2 - 400^2} &\approx 400.56429463171
\end{align}$$

Comment: Obviously, this method isn't intended to be used with perfect squares.

Comment: Linear interpolation or Newton's method (first-order approximation)

Comment: When I find the linearization of sqrt(x) I find an approximate form similar to my estimation but it comes out slightly different and is always an overestimate of the function not an underestimate.

Comment: minus, sorry JonathanZ!

Comment: Not exactly related to the question asked, but I don't understand in what sense "you technique converges towards the square root function as we estimate irrational roots towards infinity", as you only give one number for each input $n$ and not a sequence $x_k(n)$ of numbers such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k(n)=\sqrt n$. At least, I don't see in what sense this "convergence" you speak of applies to your function and not to $a:=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio - it sounds like the "convergence" is in the same sense as an asymptotic expansion, i.e. it gets better as n gets larger.

Comment: What I am trying to say is:

as n goes towards infinity, the calculation method I use to approximate the sqrt(n) gets closer and closer to being the same as the output of sqrt(n) such that as the limit of Sqrt(n) - my method = 0 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: Yes, Jonathanz described it much better than me.  Sorry, I don't speak much like a mathematician.

Comment: @JamesS. Oh, I see it now. It's because $\sqrt n-f(n)=\left(\sqrt n-\left\lfloor\sqrt n\right\rfloor\right)\left(1-\frac{\sqrt n+\left\lfloor\sqrt n\right\rfloor}{2\left\lfloor \sqrt n\right\rfloor+1}\right)\to 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's tempting to compare your formula with Newton's method, as that's the most popular way to estimate square roots. And if we notice that $b = a +1$, so $b^2 - a^2 = 2a +1$,  your estimate can be written as

$$  a+ \frac{n-a^2}{2a+1}$$

While if we apply Newton's method to $f(x) = x^2 - n$, $f'(x) = 2x$, and make our initial guess $x_0 = a$, we get

$$x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)} = a - \frac{a^2-n}{2a}$$

We can see that they are almost identical, except for the denominator getting a "$+1$" in your version. And I think we can even explain that by saying that you take for the "slope" of the function its average rate of change over the interval $[a,a+1]$, and Newton's method uses the slope of the tangent at $x=a$.

But despite how similar it looks to Newton's method, what you are doing is better described as "two point linear interpolation".

The general setting for two-point linear interpolation is that you have a function, $f()$, defined on an interval $[c,d]$, you know the value at the endpoints, and you want to estimate the value of the function at some point $x\in[c,d]$. The assumption you make is that "the slope of the line connecting $(c,f(c))$ to $(x,f(x))$ has the same slope as the line connecting $(c,f(c))$ to $(d,f(d))$. (We don't actually think that this is true, just that it is close enough to yield a good approximation.)

For your situation we'll let $f(x) = \sqrt x$, $[c,d] = [a^2,b^2]$, and the $x$-value we're interested in is $n$. Setting slopes equal gives

$$\frac{\sqrt n - a}{n-a^2} = \frac{b-a}{b^2-a^2}$$

Remember that $b=a+1$ and re-arrange a bit, and you get your formula. (Alternatively, you could choose $f(x) = x^2$ as your function. Things would get shuffled around a bit, and you'd be trying to find the $x$ value that yields a given function value, but it would all come out the same in the end.)

So in answer to your question: Yes, your formula is an instance of the general technique known as (two point) linear interpolation.

Comment: This immediately suggests an improvement over both methods: use $2a+\frac12$ in the denominator. Try it and see!

Comment: (Apologies to people who may have already read/voted on this answer. I realized that it rather missed the main point, so I rewrote it quite a bit.)

Comment: very nice, and using the 2a+1 in the denominator as opposed to b^2-a^2 will now allow for the method to also compute perfect squares!

Comment: Yeah, your restriction on excluding perfect squares seemed unnecessary. Just pick $a$ like you did before, and your formula won't change the initial "estimate". No biggie for a human applying it, but if you were including it in a computer program you could leave out an `if` statement.

Comment: very much agreed.  When I was recently playing with it, I used floor and ceil functions in excel to quickly determine "a" and "b" and Excel would naturally throw an error when I was calculating for perfect squares as $b^2 - a^2$ in the denominator would equal 0, so without considering how to remove that issue in denominator, I thought to just exclude perfect squares.

Comment: Okay, so now you gotta add two columns to your spreadsheet, one for Newton's method, and then another one that uses @TonyK's suggestion! It would be interesting to find out which does better - at this point I'm not at all sure which I'd want to bet on.